# Nginx redirect map with query string

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have nginx configuration like this:

```
map $request_uri $target {
    /test1234 https://www.somedomain.com/new_url?source=stackoverflow$is_args$args;
}

map $request_uri $target_code {
    /test1234 301;
}
server {
    listen 80 default;

    if ($target_code = 301) {
        return 301 $target;
    }
}
```

For
`/test1234` it works but if I have `/test1234?test=1` or any query string, then nginx doesn't match this redirect.
It must work for any parameters.

Is any way to set up wildcard for any query string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are using `$request_uri` variable, which contains full original request URI with arguments, so your `map` directive will never match when request have some parameters. Use `$uri` variable instead.

Secondly, imagine you have a request `http://yourdomain.com/test1234?test=test`. In `$target` you'll get `https://www.somedomain.com/new_url?source=stackoverflow?test=test`. You can use additional `map` directive in your config to avoid that:

```
map $is_args $args_prefix {
    ? &;
}

map $uri $target {
    /test1234 https://www.somedomain.com/new_url?source=stackoverflow$args_prefix$args;
}
```

And at last, I recommend use of `location` directive inside your `server` configuration block instead of `if`, for example:

```
location = /test1234 {
    return 301 $target;
}
```

If is [evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. But I have to using if because I have different redirect types: 301 302 303 and 307